# In Django I can't save my model's new content

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Once again I have a small problem to get this done in django. But at least you guys help me understand things better.

Here is my view:

```
def editUserprofile(request):
rc = context_instance=RequestContext(request)
u=request.user
if request.method=='POST':
    form = UserProfileEdit(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)
        u.avatar = request.FILES['avatar']
        u.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        u.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        u.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        u.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
        u.date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        u.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/editprofile")

else:
    u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)
    form = UserProfileEdit()
return render_to_response('users/editprofile.html',
                         {'form':form, 'u':u},
                         rc)
```

No errors but my model doesn't get modified.. here is my template too:

```
    <form method="POST" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if u.avatar %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ u.avatar }}" height="80px" />
    {% else %}
        <p>You have no avatar</p>
    {% endif %}
        <p>Change Avatar: {{form.avatar}}</p>
    <br />
    {% if u.first_name %}
        <p>First Name: {{u.first_name}}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>First Name: No first name added </p>
    {% endif %}
        <p>Modify:{{form.first_name}}</p>
    <br />
    {% if u.last_name %}
        <p>Last Name: {{u.last_name}}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Last Name: No last name added </p>
    {% endif %}
        <p>Modify:{{form.last_name}}</p>
    <br />
    {% if u.email %}
        <p>Email: {{ u.email }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Email: No email added</p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>Modify:{{ form.email }}</p>
    <br />

    {% if u.date_of_birth %}
        <p>Date of birth: {{ u.date_of_birth }}
    {% else %}
        <p>Date of birth: No birthday added </p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>Modify:{{form.date_of_birth}}</p>
    <br />

    {% if u.country %}
        <p>Country: {{ u.country }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Country: No Country added</p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>Modify:{{form.country}}</p>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

Hope you can help me guys..!

Comment: no...THANKS :D post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `form.is_valid()` True in your form validation ?